# Refactoring this code for performance

Tags: c#, performance, refactoring

Something like this:

**Assembly(A):**

```
private void MoveItems(someCollection)
{
   // more code....

   foreach( item x in someCollection)
   {
      int x = getXFoo();
      assemblyB.UpdateOrderView(x)
   }

   //more code....
}
```

**Assembly(B):**

```
private void UpdateOrderView(x)
{
    // more code....

    int y = this.ListCount();

    //......

    FinishDisplay(y)
}
```

We make a call to `MoveItems()` which has a collection and for-each loop. So if there are 600 items in the collection we are calling `FinishDisplay()` method also 600 times. But that's where I need to refactor. I don't need `FinishDisplay()` to get called each time for each item in the collection. If I can just call it one time at the end, that is enough.

So I am looking for a way to refactor this code so that `FinishDiplay()` gets called only one time. I have control over the source code so if I need to make some methd public or create some overloads of some methods I can do that too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to make `FinishDisplay` `public` and call it in the consumer instead of `UpdateOrderView`. If you need a more generic or explicit interface, you could implement a pattern like Windows Form's [`Control.SuspendLayout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.suspendlayout.aspx) and `Control.ResumeLayout` methods:

```
private bool autoFinish = true;

public void SuspendAutoFinish() { this.autoFinish = false; }
public void ResumeAutoFinish() { this.autoFinish = true; FinishDisplay(); }

private void UpdateOrderView() {
  // ...
  if(this.autoFinish) FinishDisplay();
}

// consumer
try {
  myImpl.SuspendAutoFinish();
  myImpl.MoveItems(myCollection);
}
finally {
  myImpl.ResumeAutoFinish();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What does "myImpl" refer to?

Comment: I put both methods of your assemblies A and B into a `myImpl` object for brevity. `SuspendAutoFinish` and `ResumeAutoFinish` go into assembly B, whereas the consumer's part in my code goes into assembly A.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the call to `FinishDisplay` has to stay inside `UpdateOrderView` for some reason, you can do this:

```
private void UpdateOrderView(Whatever x, bool doDisplay)
{
    // more code....

    int y = this.ListCount();

    //......

    if (doDisplay) FinishDisplay(y);
}
```

If not, why not separate it to it's own method and call it once after the `foreach` like mentioned in the comments?